# content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate error when using browserstack

Tags: browserstack

Using browserstack to test my app in different browsers and getting the following error: content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate
Is there any way to bypass that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you have to set acceptSslCerts parameter to True in your configuration.

Comment: where to set this parameter? i didn't find acceptSslCerts in my configuration.